# NLog is not logging into the database when its configured to log from code

Tags: c#, nlog

I have following console application which implements logging using NLog using the programmatic config. Currently, It is currently not logging into the database and also it does not throw any exceptions while running it. Can anybody please let me know the reason behind it?

```
using NLog;
using NLog.Config;
using NLog.Targets;
using System;

namespace Test.Logger
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var logConfig = new LoggingConfiguration();


            //dbtarget 2
            var dbTarget2 = new DatabaseTarget();
            dbTarget2.ConnectionString = "SomeConnectionString";
            dbTarget2.CommandText = @"INSERT INTO [dbo].[LogAppDetail]
                                                   ([LogAppIS]
                                                   ,[LogAppId]
                                                   ,[DN]
                                                   ,[DV])
                                             VALUES
                                                   (@LogAppIS
                                                   ,@LogAppId
                                                   ,@DN
                                                   ,@DV)";

            dbTarget2.Parameters.Add(new DatabaseParameterInfo("@LogAppIS", new NLog.Layouts.SimpleLayout("${event-properties:LogAppIS}")));
            dbTarget2.Parameters.Add(new DatabaseParameterInfo("@LogAppId", new NLog.Layouts.SimpleLayout("${event-properties:LogAppId}")));
            dbTarget2.Parameters.Add(new DatabaseParameterInfo("@DN", new NLog.Layouts.SimpleLayout("${event-properties:DN}")));
            dbTarget2.Parameters.Add(new DatabaseParameterInfo("@DV", new NLog.Layouts.SimpleLayout("${event-properties:DV}")));

            logConfig.AddTarget("dbTarget2", dbTarget2);
            // add rules
            var rule2 = new LoggingRule("LogAppDetail", LogLevel.Trace, dbTarget2);
            logConfig.LoggingRules.Add(rule2);
            LogManager.Configuration = logConfig;

            LogEventInfo theEvent = new LogEventInfo(LogLevel.Debug, "", "Pass my custom value");
            theEvent.Properties["LogAppIS"] = "12345698";
            theEvent.Properties["LogAppId"] = "1235";
            theEvent.Properties["DN"] = "DN";
            theEvent.Properties["DV"] = "DV";
            var log = NLog.LogManager.GetLogger("LogAppDetail");
            log.Log(theEvent);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you checked the InternalLogger: https://github.com/NLog/NLog/wiki/Internal-Logging ?

Comment: Have you checked if the debugger says Debug-Level is enabled for the `var log`-object ?

Comment: log.IsDebugEnabled returns true and I am not using internal logger so that cannot be a problem. All the code I have is mentioned above.

Comment: You use internal logger to diagnose why it is not working, so enable it and see what it says :)

Comment: I used internal logger to write to a file. Its working. I dont know why the above code is not working.

Comment: Happy to hear the InternalLogger is working. Now your job is to paste the output of the InternalLogger so others can help you. Unless your problem is solved? (Btw. remember first to update to latest NLog ver. 4.5.3)

Comment: Thanks @RolfKristensen for your response. I figure out the problem with the code. I enabled exception in the nlog by using LogManager.ThrowExceptions = true;
LogManager.ThrowConfigExceptions = true; in the code. I figured out that I was missing system.data.sqlclient in my project.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I figured out the reason the above code was not logging into the database.  I was missing system.data.sqlclient package in my .net core project. I figured it out by turning following exceptions in the application.

```
LogManager.ThrowExceptions = true;
LogManager.ThrowConfigExceptions = true;
```

Comment: Have created https://github.com/NLog/NLog/pull/2675 for NLog 4.5.4 that improves the InternalLogger-output for the DatabaseTarget.

Comment: Make sure to turn off `LogManager.ThrowExceptions = true`, before going into production (It should only be used for unit-testing).

Comment: @RolfKristensen Yup will do. Thank you!

Comment: please note that all exceptions in NLog are always logged to the internal log (on level error).

Answer (score 12):

To any person that's still struggling with this, as stated [here](https://github.com/NLog/NLog/wiki/Database-target#dbprovider-examples), in order to make this work from NLog 5.0 and newer versions you must include the nuget package Nlog.Database

So, this should do the magic:

```
<PackageReference Include="NLog.Database" Version="5.0.2" />
```

Comment: Lifesaver, my first born will be named after you.